# Folium error 'Map' object has no attribute 'geo_json'

Tags: python, geojson, folium

I am getting an AttributeError when using GeoJson. I've read the docs, but can't find any clues for why.

```
import folium
from folium import GeoJson 


LA_COORDINATES = (34.0522, -118.2437)
zip_geo = r'zip-code-tabulation-areas-2012.geojson'

df_zip.to_json('ticket_agg.json')
df_zip.columns = ['Zipcode','Ticket_Count']

# creation of the choropleth
map1 = folium.Map(location=LA_COORDINATES, zoom_start=12)
map1.GeoJson(geo_path = zip_geo, 
              data_out = 'ticket_agg.json', 
              data = df_zip,
              columns = ['Zipcode','Ticket_Count'],
              key_on = 'feature.properties.external_id',
              fill_color = 'YlOrRd', 
              fill_opacity = 0.7, 
              line_opacity = 0.2,
              legend_name = 'Tickets per zip')

display(map1)
```

Error:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-61-f15e83f4678b> in <module>
     19 # creation of the choropleth
     20 map1 = folium.Map(location=LA_COORDINATES, zoom_start=12)
---> 21 map1.GeoJson(geo_path = zip_geo, 
     22               data_out = 'ticket_agg.json',
     23               data = df_zip,

AttributeError: 'Map' object has no attribute 'GeoJson'
```

This is the link to the geo_json file that I'm using: http://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/boundaries.latimes.com/archive/1.0/boundary-set/zip-code-tabulation-areas-2012.geojson

Any advice would be appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

Apparently the error

> AttributeError: 'Map' object has no attribute 'GeoJson'

occurs since `GeoJson` is not a method of `Map` class.

I would suggest to upgrade to the *latest version* of folium, in which [choropleth maps](https://python-visualization.github.io/folium/quickstart.html#GeoJSON/TopoJSON-Overlays) could be created like this:

```
folium.Choropleth(
    geo_path = zip_geo, 
    data = df_zip,
    columns = ['Zipcode','Ticket_Count'],
    key_on = 'feature.properties.external_id',
    fill_color = 'YlOrRd', 
    fill_opacity = 0.7, 
    line_opacity = 0.2,
    legend_name = 'Tickets per zip'
).add_to(map1)
```

**List o changes**:

- [`folium.Choropleth` class](https://python-visualization.github.io/folium/quickstart.html#Choropleth-maps) is utilized since in folium version **0.7.0** or later  [`Map.choropleth()` moved to `Choropleth`](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/python-visualization/folium/master/CHANGES.txt)
- no presence of  `data_out` option  since [it has been removed](https://github.com/python-visualization/folium/blob/77b0b17d4ba2c3b24d677443248b91d86219b778/CHANGES.txt)
- url to GeoJSON is provided via  `geo_data` option since [`choropleth` now takes a single `geo_data` instead of `geo_path`/`geo_str`](https://github.com/python-visualization/folium/blob/77b0b17d4ba2c3b24d677443248b91d86219b778/CHANGES.txt)